# How to create a second set of records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have set of records:

```
Title     Format
ABC       CD
DEF       CD
```

I want to add a an additional format. The final set will look like:

```
Title     Format
ABC       CD
DEF       CD
ABC       LP
DEF       LP
```

What will the query look like?

Comment: From where you get the LP, is it hard code value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT title, format FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT title, 'LP' FROM table
```